# Solving recurrences

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, asymptotic-complexity

Am trying to solve the given recursion, using recursion tree, `T(n) = 3T(n/3) + n/lg n.`

In the first level `(n/3)/(log(n/3)) + (n/3)/(log(n/3)) + (n/3)/(log(n/3)) = n/(log(n/3))`.

In the second level it turns out to be `n/(log(n/9))`.

Can I generalize the above equation in the form of `n.loglogn`

This is a general doubt I've, I need an insight on this.

Note:
Any function that has to be `Theta(n^k log^k (n))` in that function k should >=1. And in this case k is -1 so master theorem doesn't come in to picture

Comment: Are you looking for the (closed-form) solution, or to find the computational complexity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is true, the Master theorem does not apply.

T(n) = 3T(n/3) + n/logn.

Let g(n) = T(n)/n.

Then n*g(n) = 3*(n/3)*g(n/3) + n/logn.

Thus

g(n) = g(n/3) + 1/log n.

This gives g(n) = Sum 1/log n + 1/log n/3 + 1/log n/9 + ...

= Theta(Sum 1/logn + 1/(logn -1) + 1/(log n - 2) + ...) = Theta(Integral 1/x between 1 and logn) = Theta(log log n).

Thus T(n) = n*g(n) = Theta(n*log logn.)

You guessed it right.

Comment: Seems like there is an error right at the step between where you introduce g(n)=T(n)/n and the n*g(n)=... part; n/logn never went up to n^2/logn

Comment: I am a little weak in calculus, can you please explain me how did you get from Sum 1/logn + 1/(logn-1) + 1/(logn-2) + ... to Integral 1/x between 1 and logn. I can understand that you are rewriting the infinite limit sum as an integral but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 5):

If you use a tree to visualize the question, you'll see that the sum of each rank is:

- rank 0:

[image]

(which is equal to n/log(n))
 - rank 1:

[image]

and so forth, with a general sum of `n/log(n/(3^i))` for each rank, i being the current rank. so, all together we get:

[image]

if we open the equation we get:

[image]

(starting from the end and going backwards.. first when i=log(base3)n and then going back)

since log base doesn't matter in theta, we get :

[image]

which is:

[image]

which is (in sigma):

[image]

which is a harmonic series, equal to:

[image]

and since ln is log with a base of e, and log bases don't matter in theta, we finally get:

[image]

which is equal to:

[image]

so, it's theta(n log log n).

Comment: I actually fixed your links before opening them and now kinda regret it :P. Just stick the math in `code snippets` - it's more readable anyway.

Comment: For anyone figuring out how harmonic series is approximated to log n checkout this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496116/is-there-a-partial-sum-formula-for-the-harmonic-series)

Answer (score 1):

`T(n)=3T(⌊n3⌋)+2nlogn` with base condition 1 when `n<=1`
By substitution method:

**Answer page 1**
[image: Answer Page 1]

**Answer page 2**
[image: Answer page 2]